# How do I translate the following sentence to Chinese? e.g. what is the correct structure of the sentence in Chinese? Thanks

Tags: translation, sentence-structure

"Her positive and persuasive tone about studying overseas indicates that studying abroad at university will broaden your horizons and make you financially independent。”

I tried translating it to "她的积极和有说服力的语气关于留学指示在大学留学让会开阔眼界和让经济独立," but was told that this is nonsensical and broken Chinese. How can I structure/restructure this sentence to make sense?

Sorry if my translation is really bad.

Answer (score 1):

To translate a long English sentence into Chinese, you may need to break it into a couple of shorter sentences. In Chinese, you can use commas instead periods to separate the sentences if they have a close relationship with each other. Sometimes, you have to add words to make the sentence complete.

(Her positive and persuasive tone about studying overseas) (indicates that) ( studying abroad at university will broaden your horizons) and (make you financially independent)。

她**用**积极和有说服力的语气，讲了到国外的大学去留学**的优点**，会让你开阔眼界，让你**能够**经济上自立。

Answer (score 0):

Start simple and build on that, or stick to short sentences.

Studying abroad will broaden your horizons.
出国留学将会开拓你的眼界。
Studying abroad will make you financially independent.
出国留学将会让你实现财务自由。

Her positive and persuasive tone about studying overseas indicates that studying at a university abroad will broaden your horizons and make you financially independent.

她对于海外留学的积极且具有说服力的态度表明了在国外上大学将会拓宽你的眼解让你实现财务自由。